# Stop ListView selected item from changing until button pressed

Tags: javafx

So I am having a problem in an app I am trying to create. I have created a sample app to demonstrate the problem. In the app, I am trying to stop the selected item in the `TableView` from changing if enter is not pressed on a `TextField`. In my implementation, I am getting a `StackOverFlow` error. I understand why I am getting the error. I am basically creating an infinite loop, but I can't think of another way to approach this problem.

If you remove this line of code:

```
if(!validateTextFields())
{
    tvPerson.getSelectionModel().select(oldPerson);
    return;
}
```

The app works like it's designed if you select a table row and then edit the text in the `TextField` and press enter on the `TextField`. Though, if you select a table row, edit the `TextField` and don't press enter, the user can select a new table row without updating the table row he/she was trying to edit. So my questions, how do I stop the user from changing the `selectedItem` if he/she hasn't confirmed the `TextField` edit by pressing enter.

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML TextField tfFirstName, tfLastName;
    @FXML TableView<Person> tvPerson;
    @FXML TableColumn<Person, String> tcFirstName, tcLastName;

    final String firstNames = "Darryl  \n" +
                                "Enriqueta  \n" +
                                "Katherine  \n" +
                                "Harley  \n" +
                                "Arlean  \n" +
                                "Jacquelynn  \n" +
                                "Yuko  \n" +
                                "Dion  \n" +
                                "Vivan  \n" +
                                "Carly  \n" +
                                "Eldon  \n" +
                                "Joe  \n" +
                                "Klara  \n" +
                                "Shona  \n" +
                                "Delores  \n" +
                                "Sabra  \n" +
                                "Vi  \n" +
                                "Gearldine  \n" +
                                "Laine  \n" +
                                "Lila  ";

   final String lastNames = "Ollie  \n" +
                                "Donnette  \n" +
                                "Audra  \n" +
                                "Angelica  \n" +
                                "Janna  \n" +
                                "Lekisha  \n" +
                                "Michael  \n" +
                                "Tomi  \n" +
                                "Cheryl  \n" +
                                "Roni  \n" +
                                "Aurelio  \n" +
                                "Mayola  \n" +
                                "Kelsie  \n" +
                                "Britteny  \n" +
                                "Dannielle  \n" +
                                "Kym  \n" +
                                "Scotty  \n" +
                                "Deloris  \n" +
                                "Lavenia  \n" +
                                "Sun  \n";

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        tcFirstName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        tcLastName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));

        tvPerson.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(getPersons()));
        tvPerson.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson)->{
            if(!validateTextFields())
            {
                tvPerson.getSelectionModel().select(oldPerson);
                return;
            }

            if(newPerson != null)
            {
                tfFirstName.setText(newPerson.getFirstName());
                tfLastName.setText(newPerson.getLastName());
            }
        });

        tfFirstName.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent ->{
            Person tempPerson = tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if(!tfFirstName.getText().trim().equals(tempPerson.getFirstName().trim()))
            {
                tfFirstName.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red;");
            }
        });

        tfFirstName.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{
            Person tempPerson = tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            tempPerson.setFirstName(tfFirstName.getText().trim());

            tfFirstName.setStyle(null);
        });       

        tfLastName.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent ->{
            Person tempPerson = tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if(tfLastName.getText().trim().equals(tempPerson.getLastName().trim()))
            {
                tfLastName.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red;");
            }
        });

        tfLastName.setOnAction(actionEvent ->{
            Person tempPerson = tvPerson.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            tempPerson.setLastName(tfLastName.getText().trim());

            tfLastName.setStyle(null);
        });

    }    

    private boolean validateTextFields()
    {
        if(!tfFirstName.getStyle().isEmpty()){return false;}
        if(!tfLastName.getStyle().isEmpty()){return false;}

        return true;
    }

    List<Person> getPersons()
    {
        List<Person> tempPerson = new ArrayList();

        List<String> tempFirstName = Arrays.asList(firstNames.split("\n"));
        List<String> tempLastName = Arrays.asList(lastNames.split("\n"));

        for(int i = 0; i < tempFirstName.size(); i++)
        {
            tempPerson.add(new Person(tempFirstName.get(i).trim(), tempLastName.get(i).trim()));
        }

        return tempPerson;
    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="575.0" prefWidth="836.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication17.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <VBox layoutX="7.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="5.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <HBox spacing="5.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="First Name" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfFirstName" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox spacing="5.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="72.0" text="Last Name" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfLastName" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </VBox>
            <TableView fx:id="tvPerson" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="tcFirstName" prefWidth="108.0" text="First Name" />
                <TableColumn fx:id="tcLastName" prefWidth="110.0" text="Last Name" />
              </columns>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </TableView>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Person Class

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Person {
    StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String firstName)
    {
        this.lastName.set(firstName);
    }

}
```

> Exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.findSubChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:62)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.insertAdd(ListChangeBuilder.java:127)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.nextAdd(ListChangeBuilder.java:254)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.nextAdd(ObservableListBase.java:179)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.setAllToMapping(SortedList.java:354)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.addRemove(SortedList.java:397)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList.sourceChanged(SortedList.java:108)
    at javafx.collections.transformation.TransformationList.lambda$getListener$23(TransformationList.java:106)
    at javafx.collections.WeakListChangeListener.onChanged(WeakListChangeListener.java:88)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:164)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.SelectedCellsMap.add(SelectedCellsMap.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2456)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2427)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2485)
    at javafxapplication17.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$initialize$0(FXMLDocumentController.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:113)
    at javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:147)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:68)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.updateSelectedIndex(TableView.java:2945)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2458)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2427)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.select(TableView.java:2485)
    at javafxapplication17.FXMLDocumentController.lambda$initialize$0(FXMLDocumentController.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:102)
    at javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$34(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:137)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
```

The exception is really long so I on posted a short version.

Comment: Would a modal dialog work in this case?

Comment: After sleeping on this last night, I came up with just disabling the `TableView` after a change is made in any of the `TextFields` and enabling the `TableView` once all changes are submitted.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: Hey @trashgod, I am not sure if my way is a true answer to the question. It was more like a workaround. I tried what you suggest, but I still had no luck.

Comment: It seem like a valid approach; you can leave the question open against a better answer.

Comment: Actually, I agree with @trashgod - as long as core fx is as badly behaved and designed as it is, any workaround that gets the requirements met is good enough (you would have to somehow tell the user that/why they are not allowed to change the selection, anyway, so disabling sounds fine). My answer is kind-of what-we-would-do-with-a-better-fx. BTW, chances to get it right are better for a ListView (vs a TableView) because there you can bypass MultipleSelectionModelBase entirly and implement it correctly - much work, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the "correct" approach would be a custom selectionModel that has a property to be disabled and does nothing in that state. Unfortunately, selectionModels are not designed for being extended/replaced by custom classes. Plus the common ancestor for selection in tabular controls is MultipleSelectionModelBase which is both entirely hidden and extremely buggy. So the chances to make a custom model behave are ... not very good.

Nevertheless, it might be possible (and with investing enough enery and resources might even work reliably ;): implement a custom TableViewSelectionModel that delegates to the default implementation TableViewBitSelectionModel (the one it grabs from the TableView), keeps itself in synch with that and installs itself to the table.

Something like:

```
public static class VetoableSelection<T> extends TableViewSelectionModel<T> {

    private boolean disabled;
    private TableViewSelectionModel<T> delegate;

    public VetoableSelection(TableView<T> table) {
        super(table);
        delegate = table.getSelectionModel();
        table.setSelectionModel(this);
        new VetoableFocusModel<>(table);
        delegate.selectedIndexProperty().addListener(c -> indexInvalidated());
    }

    /**
     * keep selectedIndex in sync  
     */
    private void indexInvalidated() {
        setSelectedIndex(delegate.getSelectedIndex());
    }

    /**
     * Does nothing if disabled.
     */
    public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
    }

    public boolean isDisabled() {
        return disabled;
    }

    /**
     * Override all state changing methods to delegate
     * if not disabled, do nothing if disabled.
     * Here: row selection. 
     */
    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row) {
        if (isDisabled()) return;
       delegate.clearAndSelect(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int row) {
        if (isDisabled()) return;
        delegate.select(row);
    }

    /**
     * Here: methods with columns
     */
    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        if (isDisabled()) return;
        delegate.clearAndSelect(row, column);
    }
    @Override
    public void select(int row, TableColumn<T, ?> column) {
        if (isDisabled()) return;
        delegate.select(row, column);
    }

    ...
```

A crude check with your example seems to be working, kind of: it does not allow the selection to change if the modified textFields are not committed. There are problems in not showing the cells in selected state and with dynamic add/remove persons and ... probably with a whole bunch of other contexts.