# Listener in Table with alert dialog

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 table and I want to populate the second table based on what row is selected in the first table. Before populating data in the 2nd table I want an alert dialog where if `Yes` is pressed new row will be selected in the first table and data will be populated but If`No` is pressed old row will be kept selected in the first table. how can I do that? I tried like below but stuck in the 2nd portion.

```
table1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
        if (newSelection != null) {


                    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Unsaved Data Will be Deleted. Continue" + " ?",
                            ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
                    alert.showAndWait();
                    if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {

                        //populate table2

                    } else if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.NO) {
                        // Cancel New Selection and keep the old one
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                            //stuck here

                            // how to keep old one selected instead new
                         //table1.getSelectionModel().select(oldSelection); //falls in a infinte loop
                            //return;                       
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }


    });
```

Comment: I think the seletion model has a `setValue()`. If so do `setValue(oldSelection);`

Comment: @Sedrick using `table1.getSelectionModel().select(oldSelection);` creates an infinite loop

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46701773/stop-listview-selected-item-from-changing-until-button-pressed

Comment: @Sedrick It's definitely more neat to implement at selection model level. Of course, it's something that over 90% of the developers (including me) aren't used (and aren't comfortable) to do.

Comment: 100% agree @Jai. I like your solution better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would help against the infinite loop, but there is no harm trying it out until someone finds a more graceful solution:

```
table1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Foo>() {
    private boolean reverting = false;

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Foo> observable, Foo oldSelection, Foo newSelection) {
        if (newSelection != null && !reverting) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Unsaved Data Will be Deleted. Continue" + " ?",
                    ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);
            alert.showAndWait();

            if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.YES) {
                //populate table2
            }
            else if (alert.getResult() == ButtonType.NO) {
                 reverting = true;
                 table1.getSelectionModel().select(oldSelection);
            }
        }

        reverting = false;
    }
});
```